# UnitTesting - custom textbox - raise Focus Event

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am currently getting into UnitTesting. Basic asserts like `equals` aren't a big deal but I have troubles raising a focus event on my custom textBox form.

For UnitTesting I am using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

Following is the shortened custom TextBox class (*the event itself is working - I have tested it the old way by adding it to a `WinForm`*):

```
public class ExtendedTextBox : TextBox
{
    // ...
        this.GotFocus += new EventHandler(this.This_OnFocus);
    // ...
    private void This_OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPlaceholderDefined() && this.Text.Trim() == this.Placeholder.Trim())
        {
            this.Text = "";
            this.ForeColor = this.CustomDefaultForeColor;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

And below is the UnitTest class to test the placeholder functionality:

```
[TestClass]
public class ExtendedTextBoxTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void PlaceholderTest()
    {
        string placeholder = "Placeholder";
        Color placeholderForeColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        Color customDefaultForeColor = Color.Beige;
        ExtendedTextBox extendedTextBox1 = new ExtendedTextBox(placeholder, placeholderForeColor, customDefaultForeColor);
        Assert.IsTrue(extendedTextBox1.IsPlaceholderDefined());

        Assert.AreEqual(placeholder, extendedTextBox1.Placeholder);

        extendedTextBox1.Parent = new StartView();
        extendedTextBox1.Focus();
        Assert.AreNotEqual(placeholder, extendedTextBox1.Placeholder);
    }
}
```

I have read in www about some delegate stuff and such but I have no clue how to include that into my UnitTest-Method. Sure, I have tried this and that but it didn't helped me. I also read that a WinForm is required, which is why I have added `extendedTextBox1.Parent = new StartView();` to my `TestMethod`.

I appreciate any kind of help :)

Best regards
AMartinNo1